# What is a quick way to check if file contents are null?

Tags: string, file, null, stream

I have a rather large file (32 GB) which is an image of an SD card, created using dd.
I suspected that the file is empty (i.e. filled with the null byte \x00) starting from a certain point.

I checked this using python in the following way (where f is an open file handle with the cursor at the last position I could find data at):

```
for i in xrange(512):
    if set(f.read(64*1048576))!=set(['\x00']):
        print i
        break
```

This worked well (in fact it revealed some data at the very end of the image), but took >9 minutes.

Has anyone got a better way to do this? There must be a much faster way, I'm sure, but cannot think of one.

Comment: You could try to make as little IO's as possible (control the chunk size to do comparisons on bigger chunks) and try streaming, but in general you need to read the whole file - this means the whole file needs to be read. You could try writing this in ANSI C, but there's no guarantee of a major speedup.

Comment: Thanks @MichałKapracki. I agree that the entire file must be read, but it definitely shouldn't take anywhere near this long. For instance, a search for a string in the same 32 GB file, done in a very similar method, took ~90 seconds. So the set(s) == set(['\x00']) is definitely the rate limiting step here and not the file IO.

Comment: Well, my python skills really suck, so I'm not sure how  that actual comparator work. I'm quite sure though you are converting the memory pointer to a string, that will take time - perhaps there's a way to compare buffers? If that's so - then you could prepare a `nul` filled buffer of let's say 16k and compare one after another.

Comment: Take a look here: https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/11/28/less-copies-in-python-with-the-buffer-protocol-and-memoryviews - this may be interesting for you.

Comment: @MichałKapracki your second idea - storing a null buffer in memory and using string comparisons - is brilliant and worked pretty well (2.5-fold speed increase, and probably will be even better if I optimise the buffer size). Thanks! Please do write it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: There, answer created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at a [guide about memory buffers in python here](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/11/28/less-copies-in-python-with-the-buffer-protocol-and-memoryviews) I suspected that the comparator itself was the issue. In most non-typed languages memory copies are not very obvious despite being a killer for performance.

In this case, as Oded R. established, creating a buffer from read and comparing the result with a previously prepared `nul` filled one is much more efficient.

```
size = 512
data = bytearray(size)
cmp = bytearray(size)
```

And when reading:

```
f = open(FILENAME, 'rb')
f.readinto(data)
```

Two things that need to be taken into account is:

- The size of the compared buffers should be equal, but comparing bigger buffers should be faster until some point (I would expect memory fragmentation to be the main limit)
- The last buffer may not be the same size, reading the file into the prepared buffer will keep the tailing zeroes where we want them.

Here the comparison of the two buffers will be quick and there will be no attempts of casting the bytes to string (which we don't need) and since we reuse the same memory all the time, the garbage collector won't have much work either... :)